# How to write this stylized pound sign?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I would like to write a pound sign [as reproduced here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#/media/File:Pfund.svg), from [this article on the #-sign.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#:%7E:text=The%20symbol%20%23%20is%20known%20variously,from%20the%20now%2Drare%20%E2%84%94.) Notice the reproduction of [Newton's hand writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#/media/File:Libra_pondo_abbreviation_newton.jpg), which illustrates the development from lb toward #.

How may I obtain the symbol I want to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It comes from the `marvosym` package. Note: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) correctly identifies this symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\Pfund

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! :) I discarded marvosym as I attempted $\Pfund$.

Comment: @Sapiens: Yes, `\Pfund` works in textmode. Note that to get a trailing space you need to add it: `Here is the \Pfund\ symbol.`

Answer (score 6):

If you have the vector image you want to include (here, [`pfund.svg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#/media/File:Pfund.svg)), you can open it in Inkscape and save it as a `.pdf` file.  You want to select the option to set the page size to the size of the exported object, so as not to have borders around the glyph, and the background to be transparent.

You can then include the image as a graphic with `graphicx`.  This code will automatically scale it to the height of a capital letter in the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \includegraphics

\newlength{\capheight}

\newcommand\librapondo{%
  \settoheight{\capheight}{H}%
  \includegraphics[height=\capheight]{pfund.pdf}%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{The {\librapondo} Symbol}

Sir Isaac Newton wrote the {\textsterling} symbol as {\librapondo}.

{\footnotesize A smaller {\librapondo}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 5):

The symbol is included in the `marvosym.ttf` font at the position 163. For example, in OpTeX we can do following:

```
\fontfam[lm]
\font\tenmarvosym=[marvosym.ttf]
\def\pfund{{\tenmarvosym\resizethefont\char163}}

\sec The \pfund{} symbol

Sir Isaac Newton wrote the £ symbol as \pfund.

{\typosize[8/] A smaller \pfund.}

\bye
```